# Link an element of string Array to a decimal value

Tags: c#, arrays, forms

So I have this string array of elements:

```
string[] words = { "My", "name", "is", "Jack" };
```

I want each element in this array linked to a specific value (decimal) but every single time I press a button for this elements to appear(in text) let's say in a textbox or a label I want to be able to press a second button that updates that decimal that is linked with the elements.Each element has its' own specific value (let's call it weight). I have tried with:

```
decimal weight1 = 0; 
words[0] = Convert.ToString(weight1); 
label1.Text = Convert.ToString(words[0]);
```

**But all it does is that it assigns the value to the element (changes it) and I don't want that**. I want them to appear as text **but only link the element not change it, and update its' linked value on the background.**

The element:

"My" is linked to `weight1`
The element "name" is linked to `weight2`, `name` => `weight3`, `Jack` => `weight4`.

How can I do that?

I am open to other suggestions if this is not possible with arrays, maybe classes or interfaces...

Comment: Have you thought of using enums

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need a custom class to define your schema. Rather than an array of strings, you should define a class that looks like the below:

```
public class WeightedWord
{
      public WeightedWord(string word, decimal weight)
      {
           Word = word;
           Weight = weight;
      }

      public string Word { get; set; }
      public decimal Weight { get; set; }
}
```

You'lll then be able to assign an individual weight to each word.

Your array will look something like this:

```
WeightedWord[] weightedWords = { new WeightedWord("My", .1), 
                                 new WeightedWord("name", .2),
                                 new WeightedWord("is", .3),
                                 new WeightedWord("Jack", .4) };
```

In your button press action, you can access the specific object you want to update.

```
weightedWords[0].Weight = .7;
```

Comment: Consider a Generic List<WeightedWord> instead of array

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need a `Dictionary<string, decimal>`. Use the keyword as your lookup and then you can simply reference it to always pull the respective numeric value.

```
var lookup = new Dictionary<string, decimal>()
{
    { "My", 0.0m },
    { "name", 0.0m },
    { "is", 0.0m },
    { "Jack", 0.0m },
};
```

Then you can update by word whenever you need to:

```
lookup["My"] += 1;
lookup["name"] += 0.5;
```

Or if in an event handler (WinForms button click for example) then whatever the text of the button is can drive it:

```
lookup[(sender as Button).Text] += 1;
```